# Finding $\frac{d}{dy} \int_{a}^{y} f(x,y)dx$ when $\int f(x,y)dx$ is non-trivial

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I ran into a problem where I had to find the following $$\frac{d}{dy} \int_0^y \sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}dx $$ and was at a complete and utter loss as to where to begin. Any and all insights regarding problems of this sort are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Leibnitz's Rule for differentiating under the integral we have

$$\frac{d}{dy} \int_0^y \sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}dx= \sqrt{y^4+(y-y^2)^2}+\int_0^y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}dx$$

Can you complete?  The integral can be expressed in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: I will if the right-hand side is integrable =). I see what you did, feel stupid now.

Comment: The integral has a singularity at $x=0$ only when $y=1$, but it is removable.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you so much!

Comment: The partial yields $\frac{(y-y^2)(1-2y)}{\sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}}$, which is zero when $y=1$!.  So, the integral is well-behaved.

Comment: And you're welcome.  My pleasure!!

Comment: Sans the two on the top (you forgot the $1/2$ from differentiating the square root), yes.

Comment: Yes, I sure did.  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks again. Time to read up on elliptic integrals, I guess.